# Jmeter - URL changes when the recorded scripts are run

Tags: url, testing, runtime, jmeter, load-testing

Please me here as we are newbie to JMeter.

We are performing a Load Test on a module called Reports.

The recorded script (URL) changes during run-time. Following is the example.

Original recorded script (URL): 
https://dev.test.com/reportserver/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2FArrowAddOnReport%2FClientsPending&AgencyName=ArrowSeed

URL generated during run-time: 
https://dev.test.com/reportserver/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2FArrowAddOnReport%2FClientsPending=&AgencyName=ArrowSeed

If you can see, "=" is added in the URL (highlighted).
Please let us know the reason and resolution to handle the same.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it happens, you should talk to DevOPS or whoever is responsible.

Personally I wouldn't use "Path" section to store request parameters, there is a "Parameters" section in the HTTP Request where you can specify required parameters and whether to encode them or not.

If you're completely stuck with an extra `=` sign I can suggest a workaround.

1. Add a [Beanshell Pre Processor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) as a child of the problematic HTTP Request
2. Put following code into Beanshell Pre Processor "Script" area:

   ```
   String path = sampler.getPath();
   sampler.setPath(path.replace("=&","&"));
   ```